# How to bind ngModel to Input Element if the same component is used for Add as well as Edit feature?

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-components

The scenario is: There are two components, one is for Adding state and other is see the list of states which are clickable and redirected to "Add" component.

I want to use same "Add" component for Add and Edit;

Here is my add.component.ts codoe:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
    import { StateService } from './state.service';
    import { State } from '../models/state';
    import { Params } from '@angular/router/src/shared';

    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';   


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-add',
      templateUrl: './add.component.html'
    })
    export class AddComponent implements OnInit {
      state$: Observable<State>;
      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router,
        private stateService: StateService) { }

      ngOnInit() {    
        this.state$ = this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.stateService.getState(params.get('id')));    
      }    
}
```

This is my add.component.html;

```
      ..................
  <div class="col-sm-10">        
      <div *ngIf="state$ | async as state">
                    <h3>"{{ state.name }}"</h3>
       </div>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="state$.name"  class="form-control" id="" style="max-width:500px"/>

  </div>
  ...................
```

The ngIf part is showing correct data; but the input textbox is not showing any value.

Please help with correct approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `*ngIF` you ar using `state` as a alias of `state$|async`. And this alias `state` scope is inside the `*ngIf`. Thats why `state` is not working in the outside of scope in `ngModel`,

```
 <div *ngIf="state$ | async as state">
      <h3>"{{ state.name }}"</h3>
  </div>
```

Use this if you don't want pipe filter inside ngModel

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="state$.name"  class="form-control" id="" style="max-width:500px"/>
```

Comment: I edited the question. Initially it was its state$.name only. But still no luck.

Comment: You should  subscribe your service call like this

 `this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.stateService.getState(params.get('id'))).subscribe((res) => this.state$ = res); `

Comment: Also response from api needs some time but the template render before your response arrived. That also causes `state$.name` undefined. So better you should initialize your `state$` variable during declaration